# How to validate a default Date on save in angualrJs using Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a date input for which I am using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
I am validating this input in angualrJs.

```
<form name="myForm" data-ng-submit="save(.$valid)" novalidate="novalidate">
  <label>Date and Time:</label>
     <div class='input-group date id='Time' >
          <input type='text' name="time" ng-model="a.time" class="form-control" data-ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.usrCreatnTime.$invalid }" required="required" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
   <div data-ng-messages="myForm.time.$error" data-ng-show="myForm.$submitted">
      <div class="error-message" data-ng-message="required">Please enter Time</div>
   </div>
</div>

<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>Save </button>
</form>
```

My directive Code:-

```
scope.datePicker = function () {
     $('#Time').datetimepicker({
         format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
         showClose: true,
         allowInputToggle: true,
         defaultDate: Date.now(),
         widgetPositioning: {
             horizontal: 'right',
             vertical: 'bottom'
         }
     });
   };

    scope.datePicker();
```

What my issue is I am showing the current date as default in the datepicker. But while validating the form it still shows the validation error `Please enter Time`. The ng-model is not updating when setting the default date. I used ng-bind and ng-value but its still showing error. Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: can you give a working demo in jsfiddle to debug

Comment: i dont see how you implement the directive datePicker in the view.